# How to achive OCR same like Office Lens?

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I am using Tesseract OCR done by Google and achieved OCR extraction but mostly many apps using whiteboard detection and Text-Over-image on their OCR application. I want to achieve same as other apps. I have attached expext output below;

[image]

The above image orange border will auto-detect only Document or receipt - I have done some research regarding this but didn't achieve the above - any suggested library or code sample will be helpful!

[image]

The above image contains OCR result which gives the result that resembles same as original image but done by placing Text-over-Image and if any Block is not scanned or error it will paste the image on that coordinate Block - any suggested library or code sample will be helpful!

I want to achieve both the task as like other OCR app done in their application.

Comment: I would suggest starting with OpenCV, but otherwise asking for libraries or code samples is off topic for Stackoverflow

Comment: How about OCR recognition output like the second image! @cricket_007